# How to remove Jenkins console logs in the build

Tags: java, jenkins

I want to remove the console output generated by Jenkins with {EnvInject] statements.

Is there a way to remove those statements from Jenkins [image: Jenkins Console Image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it personally but I found a plugin that might help. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delete+log+plugin